# FirebaseMessaging.configure() error on flutter firebase_messaging latest verison

Tags: flutter

i am trying to get message from my firebase console into my flutter app and am facing this problem with the configure method. the problem am facing basiccaly is concerned with the firebaseMessaging.configure, i have tried to migrate to the new dart code in the documentation but to no avail, i would very much appreciate it if someone could help resolve this for me, thanks in advance

```
  class PushNotificationService {
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future initialize(context) async {
    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: false,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: false,
        criticalAlert: false,
        provisional: false,
        sound: true,
      );
    }

    firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
      },
    );
  }
  
}
```

my flutter_messaging version is

```
firebase_messaging: ^9.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after some time working around it I finally figured it out. I had to get rid of the firebaseMessaging.configure and use FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(...) and FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp().listen(...) to handle onResume and onLaunch like shown below

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((event) {
  // fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
  (Map<String, dynamic> message) async => fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
});

FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
  // fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
  (Map<String, dynamic> message) async => fetchRideInfo(getRideID(message), context);
});
```